# Express $\ln 2$ as a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Determine if the following is true:

$\ln 2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n2^n}$

$\ln 2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$

So from what I know, $\ln (1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}x^n$. I can make $\ln 2 = \ln(1+1)$, so $x =1$? Then which of these 2 equations are true?

Comment: Hint: $ \ln(1+1)  = \ln(2) = -\ln(1/2) = -\ln(1 - 1/2)$

Comment: @VarunVejalla sorry, could you explain your hint? Or you can write an answer :D

Comment: @Varun Vejalla means to try $x=-0.5$ in order to check the first equality. But don't forget the first minus!

Comment: @jojobo thank you! Do I do the same with the second one?

Comment: Yes. For the second one it is exactly what you have written in your question.